# Let $g:A\to(-\infty,\infty),g(x)=\ln\ln...\ln(|x|+3);\ln$ is $n$ times. Find the minimum value of $n(n\in\mathbb N)$ for which $g(x)$ is surjective.

Tags: functions, logarithms

> Let $g:A\to(-\infty,\infty),g(x)=\ln\ln...\ln(|x|+3);\ln$ is $n$ times. Find the minimum value of $n(n\in\mathbb N)$ for which $g(x)$ is surjective (onto).

**My Attempt**:

$$|x|+3\in[3,\infty)\\\implies\ln(|x|+3)\in[1.\text{something},\infty)\\\implies\ln(\ln(|x|+3))\in[0.\text{something},\infty)\\\implies\ln(\ln(\ln(|x|+3)))\in[-\text{something},\infty)$$

Since $\ln$ input can't be negative. So, I think no more $\ln$ can be attached. So, I think it's not onto.

But the answer given is $n=4$

Comment: After posting the answer, I have just observed that your reasoning  is identical with mine, except I have ignored the fact that $\ln $ can't be applied to nonpositive numbers.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc accordingly, we will adjust the domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that
$$\ln\{[3,\infty)\}=[\ln 3,\infty)$$
Next
$$\ln \{[\ln 3,\infty)\}=[\ln(\ln 3),\infty)$$
and
$$\ln \{[\ln(\ln 3),\infty)\}=[\ln (\ln (\ln 3)),\infty)$$
But $\ln (\ln (\ln 3))<0$ hence the interval
$$[\ln (\ln (\ln 3)),\infty)$$ contains $0.$ Therefore applying next logarithm gives the entire line.